# ListView not displaying the text

Tags: android, listview

I'm using this code to search through a List and add them to a List (s is an EditText):

```
if (s != null && s.toString().length() > 2) {
                    SearchDialogList.clear();
                    for (String tmp : mSuraNameList)
                        if (tmp.startsWith(s.getText().toString()))
                            SearchDialogList.add(tmp);
                    if (SearchDialogList.size() != 0) {
                        mSearchDialogAdapter = new ListView_StartQuranSearchDialog_Adapter(Start_Quran_List2.this, SearchDialogList);
                        listview.setAdapter(mSearchDialogAdapter);
                    }
                }
```

The adapters GetView():

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.readers_choice_custom_row, null); // line
                                                                                    // 47
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tv_ReadersNames = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView_ReaderChoiceDownload);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.tv_ReadersNames.setText(SuraList.get(position));
    holder.tv_ReadersNames.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_ReadersNames;
}
```

the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_margin="15dip">

     <TextView 

android:id="@+id/TextView_ReaderChoiceDownload"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="tes"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:padding="15dip"></TextView>
/>
```

The List isnt empty, why does the ListView not show the items that are in the List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the `s.toString()` with `s.getText().toString()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_margin="15dip"
>
     <TextView 

android:id="@+id/TextView_ReaderChoiceDownload"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="tes"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:padding="15dip"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

you have given the textview inside relative layout tags

try it now.